The week parser on datetime does not work?
I'm getting Jan 1st when specifying a week number:
dw = dt.strptime("2024-26", "%Y-%W")
> datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 0, 0)

Out of curiosity I tried without the week :
from datetime import datetime as dt
dw = dt.strptime("2024-26", "%Y-%W")
dy = d.strptime("2024", "%Y")
print(dw-dy)

I would expect this to print 175 days time delta. Instead it is 0.
So why is the %W not working?
I am on python-3.11 on macOS.
